# goocanvas how to switch of antialiasing

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

Can give me someone an idea how I can switch of the antialiasing for all items in a goocanvasmm?

I tried to get the root item model but this did not contain the antialiasing property.

I could not really find any valid documentation for goocanvasmm. I really need a tutorial but I can't find some.

[edit]
Sorry, I need the code for goocanvasmm!!! not goocanvas. So please do not edit this again. Yes, it is the c++ version of gtk+ called gtkmm and the goocanvasmm

[edit]
I have now a rect in the canvas and I could get the rect->property_antialias()=???? but now i struggled with PropertyProxy.

the following both lines will not work:
1)

```
rect->property_antialias()=CAIRO_ANTIALIAS_NONE ;
```

no match for »operator=« (operand types are »Glib::PropertyProxy« and »_cairo_antialias«)

2)

```
rect->property_antialias()=ANTIALIAS_NONE ;
```

error: 'ANTIALIAS_NONE' was not declared in this scope

Thanks!

Comment: "Will not work" tells little. What's the error message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GooCanvaItemSimple`](https://developer.gnome.org/goocanvas/unstable/GooCanvasItemSimple.html) is the base class for most items. It has an [`antialias`](https://developer.gnome.org/goocanvas/unstable/GooCanvasItemSimple.html#GooCanvasItemSimple--antialias) property which is of a type that maps to [`cairo_antialias_t`](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-cairo-t.html#cairo-antialias-t).

This is for the C version, not C++, but it should be easy to map to the 'mm' versions of the docs. Here's the equivalent for [antialias in goocanvasmm](https://developer.gnome.org/goocanvasmm/stable/classGoocanvas_1_1ItemSimple.html#a2959873ae8340f87196fb356fcd1dbf3).

When you don't know where a property is, just dig in the parent classes or interfaces implemented until you find it.

Then, set the value of the appropriate [Cairo::Antialias](http://cairographics.org/documentation/cairomm/reference/namespaceCairo.html#a2cb381e7f63bef767a7d697fc5af13b4) type (which is a type defined in cairomm).

```
rect->property_antialias() = Cairo::ANTIALIAS_NONE;
```

Comment: OK, I could something like rect->property_antialias()=???? but now i struggled with PropertyProxy. I can't set a enum value from cairo directly. How to convert to the proxy?

Comment: See my last edit in my question. I added the two lines I tried.

Comment: If you're not using the Cairo namespace, you have to specify the full path to the data: [`Cairo::Antialias::ANTIALIAS_NONE`](http://cairographics.org/documentation/cairomm/reference/namespaceCairo.html#a2cb381e7f63bef767a7d697fc5af13b4) I guess (or `Cairo::ANTIALIAS_NONE`, can't remember).